# Promise async call

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am new to node js and trying to understand how to make async calls.
I am trying to wrap a function into a promise in order to make it async. For simplicity, the function is just a loop that takes time :

```
var p = new Promise(resolve => {
    for (let i=0;i<999999999;i++){}
    resolve('foo')
});

p.then(function (value) { console.log(value);});
console.log('bar');
```

I am expecting to see :

bar  // printed immediately

foo // printed after the loop finishes

Instead, they are both printed after the loop completion.
How to make the loop block run asynchronously?

Ps. Apologies for the indentation/formatting, I had to write this from a phone.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "asynchronous" ? In another thread?

Comment: you likely are blocking the IO call to write to the console.

Comment: javascript has only one thread.

Comment: the way you have written the code it will wait till your promise function finishes the operation

Comment: @daniel that is too simplified.

Comment: @JonasWilms its the way to think of how your code works.

Comment: I think a better test would be to use `setTimeout()` and adjust the timing. As the code currently stands if you place `console.log(new Date());` before and after the `for` loop and another before `console.log('bar');`, you can see that, I believe, it's working as intended. It's just that the loop is really fast. Also, `foo` does output after `bar`.

Comment: @DanielA.White it's also not correct. Most JS runs on a single thread, but you can use WebWorkers to run JS on multiple threads. In that sense, it's the same as any other language: single-threaded unless you explicitly create new threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to assume that "asynchronous code" involves concurrency, in the sense that code will run at the same time in another thread. That is not the case. Unless you start another thread by purpose, JS itself will run in a single thread. Therefore no matter what you do with promises: Either the loop runs first and then the logs run or the logs run first and then the loop runs.

You could also achieve concurrent execution through multitasking: If you stop the loop inbetween, other code can run in the meantime:

```
 (async function() {
    while(true) {
       console.log("loop");
       await Promise.resolve();
    }
 })();

 console.log("in the meantime");
```

Answer (score 2):

But there's nothing asynchronous about your promise. Creating a promise starts the execution of the function, and JS always runs to completion.

Typically, a promise is used to initiate something asynchronous, like an API call, or even a plain setTimeout, that runs *outside* JS's thread. Your code, however, will iterate through the empty loop bajillion times, and only *after* that any following lines will be run.

Replace the empty line with a timeout, and it will become async:

```js
var p = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve("foo"), 2000);
});

p.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
console.log('bar');
```